# Best way to organize book-page structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm wondering what is the best way to organize book-page content without involving taxonomies. So for example, I have a math book with a bunch of problems that I wish to list. I have a custom post type `qa` which can include a taxonomy `<book-name>`, and I want the URL to be: `<domain>/qa/<book-name>/<page-number>/<problem-number>`. So creating such a structure isn't a big deal except the `<page-number>` - there will be lots of pages, and I think that it is not practical to create so many taxonomies. So what will be the optimal implementation? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the optimal, it's one suggestion.

For me I'd created the `qa` post type as **hierachical**.

Then for every page in the book I'd created a child `qa` post using `menu_order` field to handle the page number.

This child has a 3rd level child for problems.

Hooking intro `pre_get_posts` for `qa` archive, you can set the `post_parent` to 0, so in the archive view you get only books, and not the big list of pages and problems.

Last thing to is create a rewrite rule that convert the url into some query vars.

E.g.

`<domain>/qa/<book-name>/<page-number>/<problem-number>` should be rewritten in

```
 <domain>/index.php?name=<book-name>&post_type=qa&number=<page-number>&problem=<problem-number>
```

That url will end in a very simple query where **post id = `<problem-number>`**.

Example code:

```
function my_book_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule( 'qa/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$', 'index.php?&post_type=qa&name=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]&problem=$matches[3]', 'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( 'qa/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$', 'index.php?&post_type=qa&name=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_book_rules');

function my_book_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'problem';
  $vars[] = 'number';   
  return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'my_book_query_vars'); 

function my_book_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! is_main_query() ) return;
  if ( is_archive() && $query->get('post_type') == 'qa') {
     $query->set('post_parent', 0);
  } elseif ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'qa') {
    $post = get_queried_object();
    if ( $post->post_parent == 0 && $query->get('number') && ! $query->get('problem') ) {
      // a page number is requested
      $query->set('name', '');
      global $wpdb;
      $n = intval($query->get('number'));
      $p = (int) $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'qa' AND post_parent = $post->ID AND menu_order = $n");
      $query->set('p', $n);
    } elseif( $query->get('problem') ) {
      // a problem is required
      $query->set('name', '');
      $n = intval($query->get('problem'));
      $query->set('p', $n);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_book_query');
```

In the single view template `single-qa.php` you can load sub tempalte for books, pages or problems, something like:

```
if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) {
   get_template_part('book', 'content');
} else {
  $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
  if ( $parent->post_parent == 0 ) {
    get_template_part('page-number', 'content');
  } else {
    get_template_part('problem', 'content');
  }
}
```

Another snippet is for display the book title and the page number inside the problem template (`problem-content.php` according to previous snippet),

```
$thepage = get_post( $post->post_parent);
$pagenumber = $thepage->menu_order
$the_book = get_post( $thepage->post_parent )->post_title

echo "The problem " . get_the_title() . 
  " is in the book " . $the_book->post_title .
  " at the page number " . $pagenumber;
```

Note that the code is a **proof of concept and untested**.

Comment: Thank you sir. I've got the idea. I'm new to WP and I want to ask you what does the `$query->set('p', $foo);` mean?  I've chosen to modify the architecture a bit, introducing new table which will hold data about books. Can I create my own query in `my_book_query` such that the fetched items will be available at `single-qa.php`? Because WP supplies methods such as `the_title()` and `the_content()` in `single.php`, but can I affect the way these methods work without hardcoding the core files? Can it be done in the `my_book_query` method?

Comment: I'm asking this because I have to execute a certain queries for my new tables in the db (so I don't have to create this nested structure you've suggested). I just want to execute different query for each option: if it is `qa/<book-name>` then I'll fetch on my own the pages and I would like to pass the result to `single-qa.php`. If it is `qa/<book-name>/<book-page>` I would like to execute a different query, fetching all the problems and sending it, again, to `single-qa.php`. So can I update somehow the object that operates the whole `single-qa.php` thing? Thanks.

Comment: I guess I could fetch the book name or book page in `single-qa.php` using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and then execute queries for different conditions, but I know that WP has already executed its own queries and there's some data in methods like `the_title()` and `the_content()`, so I want to avoid making unnecessary queries. That is why I want to affect the way WP fetches the object that operates `single-qa.php`. I hope that I explained myself better. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `the_title()` and other template tags use `global $post` variable to work. If you use your custom table to store data, you need extra code to make it works. It's hard to explain here in a comment, expecially without knowing how you have structured your table. The built-in query runned by wordpress known as 'main query', can be edited before it run using 'pre_get_posts' hook. My function does that, and `query->set` is the way to change the WP main query. If you work with your custom table you have to create your custom query and `query->set` will be un-useful for you, I think. @somebody